# Поиск по массиву в объекте JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, поиск, поиск-библиотек

Есть массив объектов, который имеет в себе ещё один массив, по которому нужно совершить поиск. Структура данных выглядит вот так:

```js
[
    {
        topic: "First",
        pages: [
            "Alpha",
            "Beta",
            "Gamma",
            "Delta"
        ],
        id: ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
    },
    {
        topic: "Second",
        pages: [
            "Epsilon",
            "Zeta",
            "Eta",
            "Theta"
        ]
        id: ["5", "6", "7", "8"]
    }
]
```

Нужно по заданному значению совершить поиск в массивах *pages*, и в случае успешного нахождения элемента вернуть его *id* из следующего массива. Каждый *id* соответствует по индексу элементу из первого массива ("Alpha"-"1", "Epsilon"-"5"). Есть ли какая-либо JS библиотека для подобного поиска? Пробовал Fuse.js, но она после поиска возвращает сам объект из массива, но мне нужно, чтобы возвращаемым элементом была строка из массива *pages* (или её *id*), а не весь объект. 
На вход подаётся любая строка, например *'Zeta'*. Поиск должен быть осуществлён по всем строкам массивов *pages*, и он должен вернуть индексы всех совпадений из этих массивов, в случае из примера - '6'.

Comment: Приведите пример, что именно подается на вход, и что должно быть получено в результате.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так, например:

```js
const data = [{
    topic: "First",
    pages: [
      "Alpha",
      "Beta",
      "Gamma",
      "Delta"
    ],
    id: ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
  },
  {
    topic: "Second",
    pages: [
      "Epsilon",
      "Zeta",
      "Eta",
      "Theta"
    ],
    id: ["5", "6", "7", "8"]
  },
  {
    topic: "Third",
    pages: [
      "Iota",
      "Kappa",
      "Lambda",
      "Zeta",
      "Zeta"
    ],
    id: ["9", "10", "11", "12", "13"]
  }
];

let query = 'Zeta';
let result = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  let pageIds = item.pages.reduce((ids, page, ind, arr) => {
    if (page == query) { // или page.includes(query), если нужен поиск по подстроке)
      ids.push(item.id[ind])
    }
    return ids;
  }, [])
  return acc.concat(pageIds);
}, []).join(',');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

не понимаю зачем ради такого тащить библиотеку, вот пример решения:

```js
const myTopics = [
  {
    topic: "First",
    pages: ["Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta"],
    id: ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
  },
  {
    topic: "Second",
    pages: ["Epsilon", "Beta", "Eta", "Theta"],
    id: ["5", "6", "7", "8"]
  }
];

function innerArraySearch(topicsArray, pageToSearch) {
  let answer = []; // ответ по умолчанию
  topicsArray.map(topic => {
    // проходим по верхнему массиву
    const indexOfPage = topic.pages.indexOf(pageToSearch); // записываем индекс (не)найденного элемента массива pages
    if (indexOfPage !== -1) {
      answer.push(topic.id[indexOfPage]); // записываем в переменную answer значение topic.id по индексу indexOfPage
    }
  });
  return answer; // возврат по умолчанию
}

console.log(innerArraySearch(myTopics, "Beta"));
```

Comment: По условию требуется _вернуть индексы всех совпадений из этих массивов_, а не одного последнего. :)

Comment: @Yaant, а, да, спасибо, не дочитал

Comment: @Yaant - поправил, готов к upvoting'у :)

Comment: @Yaant, и получилось твое решение

Comment: Нужна еще доработка для случая `pages: ["Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Beta"]` (у меня была та же проблема, уже исправил) :)

Comment: @Yaant reduce-callback-hell получился :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arrOfObj = [
    {
        topic: "First",
        pages: ["Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta"],
        id: ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
    },
    {
        topic: "Second",
        pages: ["Epsilon", "Zeta", "Eta", "Theta"],
        id: ["5", "6", "7", "8"]
    }
],
findPageIndex = function(arr, pageName) {
  var res = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var idx = arr[i].pages.indexOf(pageName);
    if(idx != -1){
      res.push({
        topic: arr[i].topic,
        idx: idx,
        id: arr[i].id[idx]
      });
    }
  }
  return res.length > 0 ? res : -1;
}

console.log(findPageIndex(arrOfObj, "Zeta"));
```